# Place TableView under NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationbar

First of all I have an `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and I made the `UINavigationBar` transparent by setting the BackgroundImage to an empty Image.

Now I want the TableView to start under the NavigationBar. I already tried setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` and setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` to all.

I am using the Xcode 9 Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `self.tableView.contentInset= UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0);` to start it below navigation bar

**Update:**

To change scroll indicators, you will have to set it like this:
`self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: I changed it to UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0) and it worked. Now any idea how I tell the indicator to start at the top too?

Comment: If you now change it to -64 I can finally accept your answer. :]